# Swift 2: Stop movement after applyImpulse

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

How can I stop a sprite after it has been applied an impulse like this:

```
player.physicsBody!.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(50, 0))
```

And is it possible to make the movement decrease over a time period? (2 seconds)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to stop the movement of the physicsBody, you can utilise the 'velocity' variable like so:

```
//this will reset the x, y based velocity to a halt/stop    
player.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)
//if you would also like to stop any rotation that may be present
player.physicsBody?.angularVelocity = 0
```

To address your second question you should look into 'linearDamping' to affect velocity and 'angularDamping' to affect angularVelocity (rotation). These physicsBody parameters allow you to slow the velocity over time once an impulse is applied (similar to friction).

```
//These values should be set when creating the physicsBody.
//should experiment with these values to get the desired effect.
player.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 1.10
player.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 0.25
```